# Can't create simple bucket in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can't create basic bucket.

```
testfolder:
  Type: AWS::S3::Buket
  Properties:
    BucketName: "test-storage-for-dev"
```

Error is

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::S3::Buket]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **spelling mistake**.

Instead of:

```
AWS::S3::Buket
```

you should have `Bucket` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html):

```
AWS::S3::Bucket
```